# Getting output of mysql queries synchronously in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have the following code:

```
app.get('/showtable1', (req, res) => {
  console.log("yo ho");
  mysqlconnection.query('SELECT d_name FROM datacenters', (err, rows, fields) => {
    if (!err) {
      var array = [];
      var tier = ['Class 0','Class 1','Class 2','Class 3'];
      var str = '';
      Object.keys(rows).forEach(function(key) {
        var row = rows[key];
        array.push(row.d_name);
      });
      for( var i = 0 ; i<array.length ; i++) {
        str += '<tr><td>'+array[i]+'</td>';
        console.log('sfsf');
        for (var j=0 ; j< tier.length ; j++) {
          let query1  = "SELECT * FROM `datacenters` WHERE  d_name = '"+array[i]+"' AND d_tiers LIKE '%"+tier[j]+"%'"
          mysqlconnection.query(query1,(err,rows) => {
            if(!err) {
              if(rows.length !=0) {
                console.log(1);
              } else {
                console.log(0);
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
      res.send(rows);
    } 
    else
      console.log(err);
  })
});
```

The output of this code is:

```
yo ho
sfsf
sfsf
sfsf
1
1
0
0
1
1
1
0
1
1
1
0
```

But I need the output as:

```
yo ho
sfsf
1
1
0
0
sfsf
1
1
1
0
sfsf
1
1
1
0
```

The first output is coming because the code is running asynchronously; but I need to run it synchronously. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asynchronous task does not have order. You can use `Promise` and `async/await` to get ordered output.

You can promisify your queries like:

```
function getNames() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mysqlconnection.query('SELECT d_name FROM datacenters', (err, rows, fields) => {
      if (!err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(rows)
      }
    })
  });
}

function getDatacenters(firstVal, tier) {
  const query1  = "SELECT * FROM `datacenters` WHERE  d_name = '"+firstVal+"' AND d_tiers LIKE '%"+tier+"%'";
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mysqlconnection.query(query1,(err,rows) => {
      if(!err) {
        reject(err)
      } else {
        resolve(rows)
      }
    });
  })
}
```

Then in your route

```
app.get('/showtable1', async (req, res) => {
  console.log("yo ho");
  const namesArray = [];
  const names = await getNames();
  Object.keys(names).forEach(function(key) {
    var row = names[key];
    namesArray.push(row.d_name);
  });

  const namesVal = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < namesArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < tier.length; j++) {
      namesVal.push(getDatacenters(entry, tier));
    }
  }

  // ordered array or result
  const result = await Promise.all(namesVal)
  ...
  // rest of the code
})
```

Note: I don't know which library you're using. Some libs provide `Promise` support so you don't have to write your own wrappers

Comment: did you make your function `async`?